# Past continuous of "can"

Tags: grammar, tense, past-tense

Suppose that we are at home now. You are doing something. I say: "I can help you"

How should I say this sentence tomorrow? Should I say: "I could help you"

Is the latter sentence past continuous? If so, what is the past simple of "can"? And how should we recognize them?

Comment: If I'd say it tomorrow, I would say, "I can help you tomorrow." I don't seem to fully grasp what you mean by 'past continuous' here. Would you mind adding more background information?

Comment: *Can*, like all modal verbs, is defective: it has no present participle (or any other non-finite form) and therefore cannot be cast in the progressive construction. But it makes little difference; *can* expresses a state, not an event, and therefore has no need of a progressive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If said today about today

> P1: "I need some help."
>   P2: "I *can* help you."

If said tomorrow about the day before

> P1: "I needed some help yesterday."
>   P2: "I *could/would* have helped you if I had known."

If said today about tomorrow

> P1: "I could use some help tomorrow."
>   P2: "I *could* help you *(after lunch tomorrow).*"

Comment: Thank you very much! I needed second situation. But isn't could past of can? How can we use it for future (I could help you tomorrow)?

Comment: "I could help you tomorrow" = "I can help you tomorrow" both are in the future. "I could have helped you yesterday" is in the past.

Answer (score 1):

The verb "to be able to" is the one you're looking for.

"I **was able** to help you."

or, alternately

"I **could have** helped you."